# Crashlytics Can't Download iOS Beta App

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, crashlytics-beta

I'm distributing iOS beta app via Crashlytics but my tester can't download the app.

[image]

Do you have guys any idea how to pull this off?

Thanks.

What I did:

- Verified that the provisioning profile is valid
- Removed and added the app to crashlytics
- Deleted and reinstalled the crashlytics certificate

iOS: 9.3.1

Comment: Do you have a previous installation of the app on the device? If you have it you should try to delete it and download again from Crashlytics

Comment: I just did. Still the same.

Comment: Have you added all architectures to your build? Have you added UDID of your device to provisioning profile?

Comment: @Hokage Mike from Fabric here, can you share the contents of your device log?

Comment: It turns out that the Apple Developer Account triggered the auto-renew. What I did was: Revoked all certificate created a new one, update the dev/dist provisioning profile, update the xcode's code signing -- Boom! It's working now.